# can I use async/bulk/V1/products/ for bulk update products custom attributes?

Tags: magento2, api, bulk-products-update, async

Hi Can I use PUT async/bulk/V1/products/ this endpoint bulk update some custom attributes?
However, I am not success to do so. Anyone can give me an advice what the payload should look like? Thankyou so much
"

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "203-197-1000",
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "description2",
        "value": "CHECK CHECK 555"
      }
    ]
  },
  "product": {
    "sku": "203-197-1234",
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "description2",
        "value": "CHECK CHECK 666"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to re-arrange some of the array nesting slightly, the below should work:

```
[
    {
        "product": {
            "sku": "203-197-1000",
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description2",
                    "value": "CHECK CHECK 555"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "sku": "203-197-1234",
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description2",
                    "value": "CHECK CHECK 666"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```